# developed or being developed, how different?

Tags: past-participles

Currently,  there are several projects **being developed** to help clean up space junk.

If i use **developed** instead of **being developed**,  the meaning would be changed slightly? Or no difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is tense. "Developed" is the past-tense of the verb "to develop"; "*developing*" being the present progressive.

If you say "There are several projects *developed*" it suggests that they have already been *completed* (although it isn't quite idiomatic and we would probably say "several projects *have been developed*", mainly because once a project is complete it isn't really a project anymore).

"*Being* developed" puts the past tense "developed" back into the present progressive tense, so it is clear that the projects are still ongoing.

Another way of expressing this would be "we are *developing* several projects".

Answer (score 2):

**"Being developed"** means that the projects are currently developing.
**"Developed"** means that their development has been completed.

So yes, the meaning for both is different.